# Resize video frame to fit tkinter window size when the window is resized

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, tkinter

I've written a piece of code to play a video using OpenCV on tkinter. Its part of a game I've made and compiled into an application. But I've noticed that when I play the game in a different computers, since the screen sizes are different, the video doesn't fit exactly to screen size like I want it to. The same goes for the background images I used in different pages but I wrote a piece of code to resize the background images to screen size. Here it is:

```py
    def resizeimage(self,event) :
        width, height = self.winfo_width(), self.winfo_height()
        image = self.bg_image.resize((width,height))
        self.image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        self.bg_label.config(image = self.image1)
```

I've bound this function to the label that displays the background image like this:

```py
        self.bg_image = Image.open("project_pics\\start_pg.png")
        bg_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.bg_image)
        self.bg_label = Label(self,image=bg_image)
        self.bg_label.image = bg_image
        self.bg_label.bind('<Configure>',self.resizeimage)
        self.bg_label.grid(sticky="nwse")
```

here, `self.bg_image` is the image to be displayed as background and `self.bg_label` is the label that displays the image.
I know that I can implement something similar by resizing the frames, in my code to play the video, but I cant seem to figure out a quick, efficient a way to do so. Here is the code for the video player:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Button
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import time
import cv2 as cv2
from threading import Thread
from Scripts.music_player import m_player
from Scripts.styles import Styles


# The Video Player
class VideoPlayer :
    def __init__(self,parent) :
        self.parent = parent
        self.play = False

    def player(self,vid_file,m_file,nxt_func):
        def get_frame():
            ret,frame = vid.read()
            if ret and self.play :
                return(ret,cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
            else :
                return(ret,None)
        def update() :
            ret,frame = get_frame()
            if ret and self.play :
                img = Image.fromarray(frame)
                photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
                photo.image=img
                self.canvas.itemconfig(self.vid_frame,image=photo)
                self.canvas.image=photo
                self.parent.after(delay,lambda : update())
            else :
                time.sleep(0.01)
                # stopping vid_music and starting game music
                m_player.music_control(m_file,True,-1,0)
                m_player.music_control("project_media\\signal.ogg",False,-1,0)
                nxt_func()

        def skip() :
            self.play = False

        self.parent.clear()
        self.play = True

        # starting music
        m_player.music_control("project_media\\signal.ogg",True,-1,0)
        m_player.music_control(m_file,False,-1,0)
        
        vid = cv2.VideoCapture(vid_file)
        width = vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
        height = vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.parent, width = width, height = height)
        self.canvas.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.5,anchor=CENTER)
        self.vid_frame = self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor = NW)

        # Skip button
        if vid_file != "project_media\\glitch.mp4" :
            skip_thread = Thread(target=skip)
            skip = Button(self.parent,text="Skip",command=skip_thread.start,style="skip.TButton")
            skip.place(relx=0.88,rely=0.04)

        delay = 5
        update()
```

My question is this. **How could I efficiently resize my frames to fit screen size without slowing down execution?**. Also, the function I'm using right now to resize my background images also seems to be slowing down execution. So I can see something like a glitch on the screen every time I change pages. So is there any other way I can resize my background images. Sorry if the code is a bit messy. I'm a beginner and this is the first game I've made .